# An question about preopen set

Tags: general-topology

Let$(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$. The set $A$ is called preopen if ‎$‎A‎\subset int(cl(A))‎$‎.‎ The set of all preopen sets in the space $X$ is denote by $PO(X,\tau)$.
A subset $A\subset X$ is called a QHC relative to $(X,\tau)$ if  for all  preopen cover $\mathcal{U}$  for $A$ there exist $U_{1},...,U_{n}\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $A\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n}cl(U_{i})$‎.

Question:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a space and sets $A,B \in PO(X,\tau)$ be such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.If $A\cup B$ is $QHC$ relative to $(X,\tau)$, are $A$ and $B$, $QHC$ relative to $(X,\tau)$.

my attempt:

‎‎‎‎Let‎ $ ‎\lbrace V_i‎\rbrace‎_{i \in I}‎‎‎ $‎ be any open cover $A‎$.Hence the family  $‎\lbrace V_i‎\rbrace‎_{i \in I} \cup B$ covers ‎$‎A\cup B‎$‎. By hypothesis, there exists a finite subset‎ $I_{1}\subset I$‎ ‎such ‎that ‎‎$‎A\cup B‎‎\subset cl(B)‎\cup‎\cup_{i\in I_{1}}‎‎‎cl(V_i)‎$‎‎.
Can we say $‎A‎‎\subset\cup_{i\in I_{1}}‎‎‎cl(V_i)‎$‎‎ to show $A$ is $QHC$ relative to $(X,\tau)$? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=[0,1],A=X\cap\mathbb Q,B=X\setminus\mathbb Q$.

$A$ is not QHC relative to $X$: consider the open and thus preopen cover $$\{[0,\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{n+1}):n<\omega\}\cup\{(\frac{1}{\pi}+\frac{1}{n+1},1]:n<\omega\}$$

$B$ is not QHC relative to $X$: consider the open and thus preopen cover $$\{[0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}):n<\omega\}\cup\{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1},1]:n<\omega\}$$